# Recurrence relation for number of subsets that contain no consecutive integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am currently reading my Discrete Math book and I am confused by this particular examples explanation. Can someone help me understand what this part means?

Question:

Let S = {1,2,3,4,....,n} and a_n denote the number of subsets of S that contain no consecutive integers. Find and solve a recurrence relation for a_n.

For n>= 2, if A is a subset of S and A is to be counted in a_n, there are two possibilities.

a) n is an element of A: When this happens (n-1) isn't an element of A and **A-{n} would be counted in a_n-2.**

I understand this part, but I included it anyways..

b) n isn't an element of A: For this case A would be counted in a_n-1.

Can someone explain to me why we are subtracting {n} from A in part a)? If A = {1, 4} and n = 4. Does it mean {1,4} - {4} = {1}? If so, wouldn't {1} also be included in a_n-1? I am confused with the subtracting part..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We write down, almost exactly, the argument you quoted, changing the wording a little bit in the hope things will become clearer.

Let $S_n=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. We say that a subset $A$ of $S_n$ is *good* if $A$ does not contain any two consecutive integers. For any $k$, let $a_k$ be the number of good subsets of $S_k$.

There are two types of good subsets of $S_n$. Type 1 good subsets of $S_n$ contain the element $n$, and Type 2 good subsets of $S_n$ do not contain $n$.

We first get an expression for the number of Type 1 good subsets of $S_n$, where $n\ge 2$. Such a subset cannot contain $n-1$. So any Type 1 good subset of $S_n$ is obtainable by adding $n$ to a good subset of $S_{n-2}$. Also, if we add $n$ to a good subset of $S_{n-2}$, we always obtain a Type 1 good subset of $S_n$. So there are exactly as many good Type 1 subsets of $S_n$ as there are good subsets of $S_{n-2}$. By definition there are $a_{n-2}$ good subsets of $S_{n-2}$.

Now we obtain an expression for the number of good Type 2 subsets of $S_n$. Such a subset is a good subset of $S_{n-1}$, and any good subset of $S_{n-1}$ is a good Type 2 subset of $S_n$. So by definition there are $a_{n-1}$ good Type 2 subsets of $S_n$.

A good subset of $S_n$ is either of Type 1 or of Type 2. So the number of good subsets of $S_n$ is $a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}$. We have therefore shown that $a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}$.

Comment: How come it is S_n-2 and not S_n-1?

Comment: This is for the Type 1's. A Type 1 good subset $A$ of $S_n$ contains $n$. Because it cannot contain two consecutive elements, since it contains $n$ it cannot contain $n-1$. So $A$ consists of $n$ together with a subset of $S_{n-2}$.

Comment: Ahhh, so for example, if n = 4, A = {1,4}, this means 3 cannot be part of it so that means S_3 cannot be used since it has {3} in it. So we must use S_2?

Comment: This makes so much sense now...Thanks for taking the time to rewrite the explanation provided in my textbook.

Comment: You are welcome. After you have thought about one version, a slightly different version may make things click. But it would not have happened if you had not done the initial work of thinking about the textbook explanation. Note that the recurrence is the familiar Fibonacci recurrence. This recurrence, and relatives, comes up fairly often.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Brilliant answer!